# is it possible to have Unity Fragment instead of UnityPlayerActivity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Is any possibility to run Unity in Fragment? To work exactly the same as UnityPlayerActivity?

I tried myself to create Fragment with same unityPlayer objects, overriding same methods in exactly same behaviour, and it works, but only for 1st time. If user will go outside unity fragment, and want to come back again into it, app crashes. Is any possible way to run Unity in Fragment?

Crash:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.1.17f1 (9957aee8edc2)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'coty_i820/1.9.2/PKQ1.190319.001/:userdebug/dev'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-10-11 14:12:00+0200
pid: 8035, tid: 14293, name: UnityMain  >>> com.smartmirror.wella.camera <<<
uid: 10123
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000007f051e09e4
    x4  0000007dc4dfdc68  x5  0000000000000004  x6  0000007fb2d70000  x7  00000000002bacb2
    x8  0000007dc4dff808  x9  0000000000000001  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000007dc4dfdcc0  x13 0000000000000000  x14 0000000000000140  x15 00007a5aa1bf3789
    x16 0000007f05cea958  x17 0000007faf34b510  x18 000000000000001b  x19 0000007e806b1e78
    x20 0000007e806b1e70  x21 0000000000000000  x22 0000000000000001  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000007dc4dff588  x26 0000007f09fd5ca0  x27 0000000000000002
    x28 0000007dc4dfddd0  x29 0000007dc4dfddd0
    sp  0000007dc4dfdb70  lr  0000007f051e0c98  pc  0000007f051e0c98
 
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000031fc98  /data/app/com.smartmirror.wella.camera-fvsem3uJgv1ZxeluJefTUg==/base.apk (BuildId: 11956767d321e7a95b5f3975071f632330de2d70)
      #01 pc 000000000030cca4  /data/app/com.smartmirror.wella.camera-fvsem3uJgv1ZxeluJefTUg==/base.apk (BuildId: 11956767d321e7a95b5f3975071f632330de2d70)
      #02 pc 000000000032064c  /data/app/com.smartmirror.wella.camera-fvsem3uJgv1ZxeluJefTUg==/base.apk (BuildId: 11956767d321e7a95b5f3975071f632330de2d70)
      #03 pc 00000000003222a4  /data/app/com.smartmirror.wella.camera-fvsem3uJgv1ZxeluJefTUg==/base.apk (BuildId: 11956767d321e7a95b5f3975071f632330de2d70)
      #04 pc 0000000000575fe0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #05 pc 000000000056cf88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #06 pc 00000000000cf84c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #07 pc 0000000000287e28  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #08 pc 0000000000281ce4  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #09 pc 000000000053cfcc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+300) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #10 pc 000000000055f694  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #11 pc 000000000025b498  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.llvm.3136488758)+488) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #12 pc 0000000000261048  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #13 pc 0000000000281cc8  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #14 pc 000000000053d198  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+200) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #15 pc 000000000055f714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #16 pc 000000000025b498  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) (.llvm.3136488758)+488) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #17 pc 000000000052c304  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+948) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #18 pc 00000000005760fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92) (BuildId: dc78217b700a45921bd6cdb8e86ed0a5)
      #19 pc 00000000000f439c  <anonymous:000000009adda000>
```

UnityFragment, which I created:

```
class AvatarFragment : BaseFragment() {



    private val avatarViewModel: AvatarViewModel by viewModel()



    private var unityPlayer: UnityPlayer? = null



    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        unityPlayer = UnityPlayer(activity)



        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avatar, container, false)



        avatarViewModel.run {

            screenState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, ScreenStateObserver())

            initAvatar()

        }

        initAvatar(view)

        return view

    }





    private fun initAvatar(view: View) {

        view.avatarFrameLayout.addView(

            unityPlayer?.view,

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

        )
        unityPlayer?.requestFocus()

        unityPlayer?.windowFocusChanged(true)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {

        unityPlayer?.quit()

        unityPlayer = null

        super.onDestroy()

    }

    override fun onPause() {

        super.onPause()

        unityPlayer?.pause()
    }

    override fun onResume() {

        super.onResume()

        unityPlayer?.resume()

    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {

        super.onLowMemory()

        unityPlayer?.lowMemory()

    }
}
```